# How to get a fixed DIV to stay on top of an absolute?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have have a header with a menu that is a fixed div and a "single page" that scrolls to content using jQuery. 
The problem I'm having is that since I included some css to make pictures fade to each others I had to position them as absolute and relative.

Now when the page scrolls the images with the fade effect scrolls on top of the fixed header.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Check out the page at http://www.axeltagg.com/test/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just Add Z-index to header

```
z-index: 999;
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.  **for reference** [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Make the `z-index` of the fixed div larger than the `z-index` of the absolute div.

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index` to your header -

```
#header {
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```